# Using CSS for customizing my WordPress site not working reliably

Tags: css, wordpress

I read about using a child theme to make it fast and easy to modify a WordPress theme.  I followed directions and created a directory with a file style.css containing the following

```
/*   
Theme Name: IBD Page
Description: IBD Page is based on Twenty Sixteen
Template: twentysixteen
*/
@import url(../twentysixteen/style.css);

article header h1 {font-size:3em}
article header h1 {color:blue}
```

However, the element only partly changes. The color changes to blue, but the font-size does not.  I tried a few different font sizes.

Why didn't that work?

======= :-)  ======= :-)  ======= :-) =======

Arthur gave the correct answer, below. For those that get here, the following works for this problem when using a child of the Twenty Sixteen theme.

```
/*   
Theme Name: IBD Page
Description: IBD Page is based on Twenty Sixteen
Template: twentysixteen
*/
@import url(../twentysixteen/style.css);

/* Making the article titles 20 point */
.content-area .site-main article header h1,     
article .entry-header .entry-title a 
    { font-size: 20pt; }
```

Comment: If Twenty Sixteen sets the font size itself, are its CSS selectors more specific than yours? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: @Arthur That was the answer! Please make an answer out of your comment and I'll approve it and pop up your reputation as you deserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twenty Sixteen sets the font size itself, and its CSS selectors are probably more specific than yours. If you make your selectors more specific, your rules will override the parent theme's rules.

See [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more detail on specificity.

Comment: It worked! Using '.content-area .site-main article header h1, article .entry-header .entry-title a' got all titles. I was going to dig around in a couple of directions not knowing what gotchas lurk in WordPress, the platform being new to me. You saved me hours of needless searching and directed me right to the CSS. I also misunderstood the cascade. I thought the last place that specified format won, but it is really the last place with the same or greater specificity. Your reference was really good, too!

Answer (score 1):

your statements should end with a semi-colon
and because both statements relate to the same tag I would put both of them together _

try this

```
article header h1 {
  color : blue;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

Comment: While stylistically grouping the selectors is usually done, and certainly, when you want a style to apply to groups of selectors, putting the selectors together is very appropriate. However, there is no requirement for that, and separate selectors are a valid construct. Also, semicolons are separators rather than terminators in a declaration block. The reason I put my question as I did was to signal to the contributors that I was able to identify the element (the declaration color:blue) and that the font-size was the problem, specifically.

Comment: yep @kd4ttc _ I do agree _ I was only stating how I would have written it _ and specifically because I know Wordpress to be tricky and somewhat labyrinthine with code _ Anyway_ pleased to see you got the answer you needed : )